# General query on overall architecture/framework for desktop and mobile app and admin webpage

Tags: python, android, postgresql, architecture, frameworks

I have learned Python specifically for developing a desktop app for a new business idea. In addition, I also need to learn Android for developing the mobile app. Here is how it would work in brief.

1. A desktop GUI app would be installed and used by users on their respective desktop. They would use it and send/receive some data.
2. A mobile app would fetch the data uploaded by users and give customers the information.

I play to use the following.
1. Python for the desktop GUI app (already done).
2. Postgresql database. Currently, it's installed in my system, it needs to be in some server or cloud so that the users (numbering ~10k) can use it once the system goes into deployment.
3. An admin webpage for allotting user rights and also for data analysis of uploaded data has been developed in Django, and also the REST API using Django.
4. In the process of developing an Android app.

Everything is in bits and pieces and I am somewhat lost on how the entire thing would turn out finally.

Can someone pls explain the entire architecture of how it would finally be? Things like how GUI would connect to Postgresql on the server, sockets required, APIs required, where would the logic be stored, how would Android app fetch data from the PostgreSQL database, APIs required for mobile app, how the admin webpage for allotting user rights would fetch or send data to Postgresql on server etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your question is too broad to be answered here. And of course there can be plenty of architectures and also frameworks for doing this job. Choosing one is something like an art which requires experience and seeing different case studies. I suggest you to read some tutorials on applications like what you want to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, any suggestions on specific tutorials which may be available? Because it's a broad topic, looking for specific tutorials would be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is frontend-backend-database architecture. GUI and mobile apps shouldn't communicate with the database directly. Between them should be hosted servers. As you mentioned you can use Django and build upon Django DRF for REST API.

Your architecture could look like:
[image: frontend-backend-database]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really clarifies things a bit. Where would the Django REST API be hosted? On the server that you mentioned? Right now I'm using Django test server for development. Can I use something like Heroku cloud for deployment? Alos, can the Android app fetch data via the Django REST API? Thanks.

Comment: You can host your DRF application on every cloud provider you like. It requires some DevOps skills to host it on AWS or Azure.
Getting back to your question regarding Heroku. Yes, you can host it on Heroku. Here you have documentation [Deploying Python and Django Apps on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python). Probably you will also need to create addon with Postgres

Comment: Thanks a lot Artur